# Not able to understand how this k-fold validation algorithm works?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science

```
for i in range(k):
        print('processing fold #', i)
        val_data = train_data[i * num_val_samples: (i + 1) * num_val_samples]
        val_targets = train_targets[i * num_val_samples: (i + 1) * num_val_samples]
        partial_train_data = np.concatenate([train_data[:i * num_val_samples],train_data[(i + 1) *num_val_samples:]],axis=0)
        partial_train_targets = np.concatenate([train_targets[:i * num_val_samples],train_targets[(i + 1) * num_val_samples:]],axis=0)
```

I am not able to understand the slicing part in this code.
The shape of the input data set `train_data` is `(404,13)`.
`k` is `4` and `train_label` has shape `(404)`.
I know that I have to create a 4 fold validation stack with 101 data set each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of training set is small,then the number of validation set derived out of the training set will be very small. This will lead to high variance in validation set and hence the validation score may change a lot. Hence what we do in this case is that we split the training data into k partitions (typically k = 4 or 5) each containing `len(train_data)//k` number of training samples. We train the model for k-1 partitions and evaluate for remainig partitions. This is done k times. For example here the 404 training samples totally. We will create k = 4 ie four fold validation stack where each fold will have 404//k = 10 training samples. In the first iteration, we will train for 10->404 ie 303 training samples ie last 3 folds out of 4 folds and validate for the first fold or 0->101 ie 101 training samples. In The next iteration,we will validate for the 2nd fold or 101->202 training samples and train for 0->101 ie 101 ie 1st fold and 202->404 ie 202 ie last 2 folds.

We continue this k times until the model has been validated for all the k folds. See this video for better understanding: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJo0uNL-5Qw from 3:30 example.